# How to input user data with an EditText in Android Auto? My App needs 3 EditText to collect 3 data from users, realize calculation and give a response

Tags: java, android-edittext, android-auto

I know that it is possible to have fields (I just don't know if they are EditText) to collect user data in Android Auto as in CarStream, CarTube, Fermata Auto, among others. However these developers do not share how to do this.

I've already tried using EditText in several codes where I can already print texts on the car's multimedia screen, just missing to collect the 3 data from the users to perform the calculation and print the answer on the screen.

Before putting the code below, I will quickly explain what my app does in the mobile version and what I want to reproduce in Android Auto: It collects from users the price of the 3 types of fuel that we have in Brazil and calculates which is the most advantageous depending on the price practiced at a given gas station (here there is a very large variation in prices from station to station) and some variables of each type of fuel.

Below are the code snippets (automotive) where I can display texts on the car's multimedia screen and just below the code (mobile) where the EditTexts are that do not work when combined with the automotive code.

```
public class HelloWorldScreen extends Screen {
    public HelloWorldScreen(CarContext carContext) {
        super(carContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Template onGetTemplate() {
        Row row = new Row.Builder().setTitle("AA Br Combustível Ideal").addText("Automotive Version").build();

        return new PaneTemplate.Builder(new Pane.Builder().addRow(row).build()).setTitle("MTT").build();

    }
}


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editPrecoAlcool = findViewById(R.id.editAlcool);
        editPrecoGasolina = findViewById(R.id.editGasolina);
        editPrecoGas = findViewById(R.id.editGas);
        textResultado = findViewById(R.id.textResultado);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular);
```

Comment: I discovered 3 libraries that can solve my problem. However, when importing these libraries, Android Studio presents an error as if they do not exist (marking in red saying this: Cannot resolve symbol ....). Could I get these libraries externally and then import them into my project in Android Studio? The libraries are below:

import android.support.car.input.CarRestrictedEditText; (CAR in red)

import com.google.android.gms.car.input.CarEditable; (ANDROID in red)

import com.google.android.gms.car.input.CarEditableListener; (ANDROID in red)